# delete sql row after echo onClick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, sql

I am making a program for a quiz show in our school programme. I have a table that contains WHO asked the question (among the teachers), WHAT is the question and another table as to what the answer to that question is. So, I have a table with THREE COLUMNS.

Now, what I was trying to do is that when the page loads, it will display a number of links labeled . I echoed each link such that when you click any of them, a random row will be taken from MySQL table and the "Question" as well as who asked that particular question will be displayed publicly.

so far, i was able to do all that just fine. But here's the problem.

I want to do it in such a way that after clicking the question, (after displaying it, to be exact,) that specific row will be DELETED from the MySQL table. I didn't want to use a timer because the time allotted for each question differs. I was wondering if there is some kind of "after click" function (or some way to do it) in javascript and AJAX. or perhaps a PHP code?

sorry for the noobish question. History teacher here. :)

by the way, here is a part of my code:

```
<?php 
    $checkrow = $db->query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE `who` = $teachers");


    while ($row = $checkrow->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
         $who = $row['who'];
         $question = $row['question'];  
         $date =$row['date_asked'];

         $ask = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM teachers WHERE science = $from AND who = $teachers");  
         $count = $ask->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

         if($count[0] == 0) {
              echo '<a href="#" onClick="readmsg();"> MYSTERY QUESTION </a>';
              $fromwho = "From science Department.";
              echo "<br>";
         } else {
              echo '<a href="#" onClick="readmsg();"> MYSTERY QUESTION </a>';
              $fromwho = "From your Arts Department.";
              echo "<br>";
         }
     }
?>
```

and here is my javascript.

```
<script language="javascript">
      function readmsg(){
           var qst = "<?php echo $question; ?>";
           var dte = "<?php echo $date; ?>";
           var frm = "<?php echo $fromwho; ?>";

           document.getElementById("displaymsg1").textContent = qst;
           document.getElementById("displaymsg2").textContent = dte;
           document.getElementById("displaymsg3").textContent = frm;
      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1st, you have to make page `delete_question.php` (or method like this):

```
<?php 
$db->query(('DELETE FROM questions WHERE ID=' . $_GET['uid']); // make it safer
echo '{result:"done"}';
?>
```

2nd, make delete onclick handler function with ajax sends UID to specified

```
function delete_question(el) {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'delete_question.php',
        dataType : 'json',
        data : {
             uid : el.dataset.uid
        }, 
        success : function(response) {
             // remove line?
             $(el).parent().remove();
             alert(response.result);
        }
   });
```

3nd: add handler to element

```
<a href="#" onclick="delete_question(this)" data-uid="<?php echo $row['ID'] ?>">
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. I will do this right away and update. :)

Comment: for some reason, the row is not deleted. =(